# do while loop is not working. the do statement is repeating

Tags: c#

I have an logic error in my code. I can't figure out where i screwed up.I am new in C#.

the `do{ }` is repeating even though i put the right value or the false value. It is not going to the `while` statement

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is you gender?");
    gender = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (gender != "male" || gender != "female" || gender != "others");
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your gender.");
}
```

Comment: I guess you are meant to use `&&` operator instead of `||` in your while statement.

Comment: Your condition is always true.

Comment: On another note, what if a user types `Male` or `Female` etc... IMHO redo your checks...

Comment: You might be slightly confused on what a do/while loop is as well. The block of code you have following the while part is not linked to the while in any way (the while doesn't get it's own block). That's going to get executed after your loop is finished. Every time.

Comment: @ScottHannen - That's not true. That's just an arbitrary block of code under the while. The code inside that block will never loop and would only be called once (assuming the do/while ever terminated). There is just a do/while and a code block. There is no while loop here. Essentially, that last pair of curly brackets are meaningless.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb - You're right. I deleted my comment so I can pretend I didn't say whatever it was I said.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like (not tested):

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your gender.");    
do
{
            Console.WriteLine("What is you gender?");
            gender = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}
while (gender != "male" && gender != "female" && gender != "others");
```

This ensures that the loop executes at least once but prompts for each attempt. The initial `writeline` is optional

Answer (score 2):

Use "And" sign `&&`, like:

```
do
{
   Console.WriteLine("What is you gender?");
   gender = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (gender != "male" && gender != "female" && gender != "others");
```